# JACOB - ALM OTA connection - How to retrieve the list of testsets

Tags: jacob, hp-quality-center

I am trying to get list of testsets using JACOB- ALM connection.
I am using below code to establish connection.

```
Dispatch.call(disp, "InitConnectionEx", "url");
Dispatch.call(disp, "Login", "user","password");
Dispatch.call(disp, "Connect", "Domain","Project");
```

Can someone suggest me code to connect to testlab and get the details from testset?

Comment: I can connect to Test plan using code
    Dispatch treeMgr=Dispatch.get(axc, "TreeManager").toDispatch();
    Dispatch testFolder=Dispatch.call(treeMgr, "NodeByPath", "Path").toDispatch();

What is the test lab equivalent to test plan's "treeManager"?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the TestSetTreeManager. It has a method FindTestSets which gets you a list of test sets. Some example:

```
private static void printTestSetNamesFromFolder(String testLabPath)
{
    Dispatch treeManager = Dispatch.get(disp, "TestSetTreeManager").toDispatch();
    Dispatch testLabFolder = Dispatch.call(treeManager, "NodeByPath", testLabPath).toDispatch();
    Dispatch testSets = Dispatch.call(testLabFolder, "FindTestSets", "").getDispatch();
    EnumVariant testSetsList = new EnumVariant(testSets);

    while (testSetsList.hasMoreElements())
    {
        Dispatch testSet = testSetsList.nextElement().getDispatch();
        System.out.println(Dispatch.get(testSet, "Name").getString());
    }
}
```

I am new to Jacob, so I don't exactly know when to use `get()` or `call()` or `toDispatch()` or `getDispatch()` but the example should work fine.